# MultiTrigger Condition to same binding/ Switch controls using Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I am trying to have `p:MarqueeTextBlock` to only scroll on `ListBox` `IsSelected` under `TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"`.

Having trouble to work out adding a `MultiTrigger` conditions (fired when `IsSelected` becomes `True` or `False`) to change the `Property="Scroll"` of the `p:MarqueeTextBlock` to `Off` or `LeftTypewriter`. In addition not sure how to reference the `p:MarqueeTextBlock` in the `DataTemplate`; perhaps if I provide it an `x:Name`? However I get `Template property has already been set on DataTemplate`.

I need to add `AOTbMain_MARQUEE` somehow in `x:Key="ListBoxStyle_GAME"` like:

```xml
<p:MarqueeTextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Style="{StaticResource AOTbMain_MARQUEE}"/>
```

Code with above reference not added:

```xml
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Plugin.Controls;assembly=Plugin.v1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="2160" d:DesignWidth="3840">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Image x:Name="SelectedGameOverlay" Source="{}pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/Selected Game Overlay.png" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Visibility="Hidden" />
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="SelectedGameTextColour" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="SelectedGameOverlay" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="SelectedGameTextColour" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="SelectedGameOverlay" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="SelectedGameTextColour" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="p:AutoscrollListBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle_BASE" TargetType="p:AutoscrollListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}">
                <Setter Property="ScrollMode" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="AOTbMain_MARQUEE" TargetType="p:MarqueeTextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Scroll" Value="LeftTypewriter" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollDelayBeg" Value="0:0:5" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollDelayEnd" Value="0:0:3" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollSpeed" Value="0:0:5" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle_BASE_INDXFADER" TargetType="p:AutoscrollListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle_BASE}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IndexVisibility}" Value="Visible">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IndexVisibility}" Value="Hidden">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle_BASETB" TargetType="p:AutoscaleTextBlock">
                <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
                <Setter Property="TargetFontSize" Value="30" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle_GAME" TargetType="p:AutoscrollListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle_BASE_INDXFADER}">
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <p:AutoscaleTextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle_BASETB}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyleSearch" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="SelectedSearchTextColour" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="SelectedSearchTextColour" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyleSearch" TargetType="p:AutoscrollListBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyleSearch}" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle_INDX" TargetType="p:AutoscrollListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxStyleSearch}">
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyleSearch}">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <p:AutoscrollListBox Name="Index" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle_INDX}" Visibility="{Binding IndexVisibility}" />
        </Viewbox>

        <p:AutoscrollListBox Name="Items" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle_GAME}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I cannot find the `MarqueeTextBlock`in your XAML. Only tons of styles. Also do you mean `ListBoxItem.IsSelected`? `ListBox` doesn't have such a property.

Comment: `MarqueeTextBlock` is called by `TargetType="p:MarqueeTextBlock"`. Not sure if it can be added to `TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"` section under `<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />`. [This](https://mega.nz/#!0gYREIpb!O1ZNKdES-8Nq5xcwOUlpzD02zGObHwV9-YY2Bc8SevM) is how it looks like with the text trimmed but I am trying to do the `p:MarqueeTextBlock` effect on it so when its selected you can see the rest of the text.

Comment: The style `AOTbMain_MARQUEE` can only apply to instances of `MarqueeTextBlock`. You have to add it to the visual tree at some point. Where do you want it to appear? If it should be part of the `ListBoxItem` then add it there.  Where do you want it to be?

Comment: Please see this [example](http://pastiebin.com/embed/5dc54ef9428d8)

Comment: So you want to have a `TextBox` with trimming when the item is not selected. But if selected the you want to show the marquee effect control?

Comment: Is it possible to have TextTrimming on everything but if item is selected the marquee effect control shows?

Comment: That's what my answer is supposed to do.

Comment: Let me know if I can help.

Comment: Check the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `Style` will show the `AutoscrollListBox` as content of the `DataTemplate`. Once the `ListBoxItem` is selected it will display the `MarqueeTextBlock` instead. If unselected it will switch back to the `AutoscrollListBox`.

**Solution 1**

```
<Grid>
  <AutoscrollListBox Name="Items" >
    <AutoscrollListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
          <AutoscaleTextBlock x:Key="AutoscaleTextBlock" 
                              Text="{Binding Title}" 
                              Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle_BASETB}"
                              x:Shared="False" />
          <MarqueeTextBlock x:Key="MarqueeTextBlock"
                            Text="{Binding Title}"                           
                            Style="{StaticResource AOTbMain_MARQUEE}"
                            x:Shared="False" />
        </DataTemplate.Resources>

        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentPresenter" />

        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" 
                       Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" 
                    Property="Content" 
                    Value="{StaticResource AutoscaleTextBlock}"/>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" 
                       Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" 
                    Property="Content" 
                    Value="{StaticResource MarqueeTextBlock}"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
      </DataTemplate>
    </AutoscrollListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </AutoscrollListBox>
</Grid>
```

**Solution 2**
In case you are working with nested resource dictionaries and can't apply the `x:Shared` attribute you can swap the controls directly from the `Trigger`:

```
<Grid>
  <AutoscrollListBox Name="Items" >
    <AutoscrollListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentPresenter" />

        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" 
                       Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" 
                    Property="Content">
              <Setter.Value>
                <AutoscaleTextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"                           
                                    Style="{StaticResource AOTbMain_MARQUEE}" />
               </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" 
                       Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" 
                    Property="Content">
              <Setter.Value>
                <MarqueeTextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"                           
                                  Style="{StaticResource AOTbMain_MARQUEE}"/>
               </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
          </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
      </DataTemplate>
    </AutoscrollListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </AutoscrollListBox>
</Grid>
```

**Solution 3**
Or toggle the `Visibility`:

```
<Grid>
  <AutoscrollListBox Name="Items" >
    <AutoscrollListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <AutoscaleTextBlock x:Name="AutoscaleTextBlock" 
                              Text="{Binding Title}"                           
                              Style="{StaticResource AOTbMain_MARQUEE}"
                              Visibilty="Visible" />
           <MarqueeTextBlock x:Name="MarqueeTextBlock" 
                             Text="{Binding Title}"                           
                             Style="{StaticResource AOTbMain_MARQUEE}"
                             Visibilty="Collapsed" />
        </Grid>

        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}" 
                       Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="AutoscaleTextBlock" 
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="MarqueeTextBlock" 
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Visible" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
      </DataTemplate>
    </AutoscrollListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </AutoscrollListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202120/discussion-on-answer-by-bioniccode-multitrigger-condition-to-same-binding).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me get this sorted!

Comment: I am happy to help. You seem to be nice.  Just tell me if you need more help. I am not sure if Visual Studio 2019 Community is still free. But 2017 was free. If it's still free you should try it. Especially for WPF and XAML you get more productivity support like code suggestions which is very helpful. Maybe you give it a try.